# How do I reword this sentence as an effective description for a resume?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I took over the bookkeeping for a small company after they had been methodically robbed (over the course of a year) by their previous bookkeeper.  How do I word this in a manner appropriate for use on a resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to describe the value you added to the company, not the company's history.  Save the specifics for how the company got into trouble for the interview.  Use power words.

> Reduced risk, created and maintained a rock solid bookkeeping process for a small business.

This is a perfect setup for an interview question. "I see you reduced risk, can you tell me more about that...."  Boom!  launch into the story of bad ethics and how you saved the day.

Comment: Well done. But "rock solid" should have a hyphen: "rock-solid".